# Multiprocessing and multithreading with tkinter in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Im having an runtime error using multiprocessing with tkinter, i'm not completely familiarized with tkinter.
The program have two processes one have two threads, one of them take data and send it to another one that send in internet. (I want a multithread to not miss any data while sending the previous one to internet) when the data is sent, the second process (the one that control the user window) put the data in a textbox of the window.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
def take_data():
    while True:
        data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        queue.put(data)
        time.sleep(1)
def send_data_internet():
    while True:
        local_data = cola.get()
        print("Sending data to internet:", local_data)
        main_window.after(0, refresh_label, local_data)
def refresh_label(data):
    label_data.config(text=str(data))

main_window = tk.Tk()

label_data = tk.Label(main_window, text="waiting data")

label_data.pack()

queue = mp.Queue()

secundary_process = mp.Process(target=send_data_internet) #CRASH HERE
thread_local_data = threading.Thread(target=take_data)

secundary_process.start()
thread_local_data.start()

main_window.mainloop()
```

The runtime error is:

```
RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.
This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
```

I don't have this last instructions. Do I need them using tkinter?

I work with multithreading before working fine my problem is the migration to tkinter

Comment: Python is not kidding, you really need the import guard `if __name__ == "__main__":`.  I can't run your program but it looks like you need to put this line before `main_window=tk.Tk()` and then indent all the lines thereafter.  This has nothing to do with tkinter, it's a general requirement for multiprocessing programs.

Comment: You need to put all tkinter related code in the main block inside `if __name__ == "__main__":`, i.e from line `main_window = tk.Tk()` to the line `main_window.mainloop()`.  Also `cola` is undefined.  And note that you cannot share tkinter widgets across processes.